# Why I have this error "Uncaught TypeError: posts.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, function, dictionary, undefined

[I changed posts to posts? and i've tested others solutions but nothing does working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfRhl.jpg)

I used the && on map but nothing, on useState i've added interface

which uses the same json syntax and i've modified

```
useState([])
```

to

```
useState<Pulse[]>([])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `data.pulse.outputValue` is string, but not array. Check response in your browser:
https://beacon.nist.gov/beacon/2.0/chain/last/pulse/last

`.map(...)` function works only with arrays, but not strings.